# Path JSON to return only the titles?

Tags: jquery, json

Hi guys I'm doing my first ajax application, already got a lot, but it does not hit the road for the titles.
Json in this way: "json.query.results.channel.item.title"

I return all the arrays, but I can not set the path to the title, can someone help me?

jQuery:

```
var main = function () {
    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (json) {
            console.dir(json.query.results.channel.item);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });

    var titles = item.map(function (item) {
        return item.title;

    });

    $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li><li>'));


}(jQuery);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYwX3/)

Comment: You never defined `item`. also, `async: false` doesn't work with `jsonp`.

Comment: but console.dir(json.query.results.channel.item); work, return me

Comment: Right, but that has nothing to do with `item`.

Comment: so.. as would be the variable to that path? thanks.

Comment: It would be `json.query.results.channel.item`, as you have already found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `item` variable is not defined: the only `item` that you have is a property of the `json.query.results.channel` object which is currently available only within the scope of your `success` handler. Also, using `async:false` doesn't work with jsonp, so put all of the data processing code in the success handler:

```
    success: function (json) {
        var titles = json.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
            return item.title;
        });
        $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li><li>'));
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eYwX3/2/

Comment: perfect, if I wanted to add other variables I just put lowers the other variable?
thanks.

Comment: If you want to use other properties of each `...item`, in addition to `.title`, it might make sense to process `json.query.results.channel.item` with an `$.each()` loop rather than `.map()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn or better yet, return the complete li rather than just the title inside the .map (responding to comment).